# How to debug the code to be tested

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

When I run an rspec test, I want to get details of the variables in the code that is tested. I tried to use rubymine, but it is complicated to configure. Sublime text 2 is a ruby friendly editor, so I wish someone can recommend some plugins to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no similar package for Sublime. What you are looking for is a debugger (in fact, RubuyMine integrates the Ruby debugger).

The most common Ruby debugger is the [debugger gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/debugger). Simply install it, then place a `debugger` statement where you want to debug the execution and you'll be able to jump in the middle of the running spec execution.

Comment: I know RubyMine debug very nice, But could you please tell me how to use RubyMine debug when debug the code to be tested?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't know of any Sublime plugins that will do this for you, but...

Check out [the pry gem.](https://github.com/pry/pry)  This will allow you to peek into your code, view instance variables, modify settings, etc. within the middle of an Rspec test.

Comment: Thanks, the pry seems some complex for debug, I choice debugger, It works fine!